# Не попадаю в директорию сервера

Tags: python, сервер, windows-7

Всем привет. Есть сервер на `Bottle: Python Web Framework` (спасибо пользователю [jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs)), хостом указал `IP` компьютера, а не `localhost` (как во всех примерах). Сервер в итоге запускается, но вбивая в адресную строку `192.168.0.2:800` не попадаю в директорию, из которой запущен сервер. Пробовал на компьютере на работе, такой проблемы нет. Брандмауэр и антивирус отключил. OC `Windows 7`. У кого-нибудь была такая проблема?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bottle import route, request, run, template 
$pip install bottle

temperature = None

@route('/')
def index():
    global temperature
    temperature = request.query.temperature or temperature
    return template('<b>Temperature: {{temperature}}</b>',
                    temperature=temperature)

run(host='192.168.0.2', port=800)
```

Comment: _не попадаю в директорию, из которой запущен сервер_ А куда попадаете?

Comment: Никуда - "Не удается получить доступ к сайту". Проблема не с сервером - на другом компьютере все работает, как надо.

Comment: Если вы мне скажите название вашего сервера, я помогу.

Comment: У него нет названия - http-сервер написан на python с помощью библиотеки bottle, вставил код в вопрос @Insider

Comment: какой `IP адрес` у машины, где запущен данный фреймворк?

Comment: @Insider 192.168.0.2, слушает порт 800.

Comment: @soadmized как вы на сервер заходите? (точная команда/адрес). Правильный порт? Запущен ли скрипт с кодом сервера? Попробуйте для отладки порт больше 1024. Какой ip у машины, где сервер запущен? (выполните ipconfig). Совпадает ли этот ip с указанным в вопросе? С какой машины вы пытаетесь на сервер зайти? Находится ли она в той же сети, что и сервер? (y вас частный ip, не доступный из интернета).

Comment: @jfs просто вбиваю в адресную строку браузера 192.168.0.2:800 (все, как указано в скрипте). Сам скрипт конечно запущен. Адрес машины - 192.168.0.2. Зайти пытаюсь с той же машины, где запущен сервер. Проблема не в скрипте - на другой машине все работает, как нужно.

Comment: @soadmized вы уверены, что скрипт с ошибкой не завершился? Порт более 1024 пробовали? Вам ipconfig показывает 192.168.0.2? Работает ли скрипт, если на localhost:8000 заменить везде? Работает ли `py -mhttp.server --bind localhost 8000`?

Comment: @jfs скрипт точно работает, не вылетает с ошибкой. Порт более 1024 пробовал (а именно 8080). Ipconfig показывает именно 192.168.0.2. И да, если заменить на localhost:8000 (или любой другой порт), то в директорию попадаю.

Comment: Работает ли `py -mhttp.server --bind 192.168.0.2 8000` и после  `py -mwebbrowser http://192.168.0.2:8000`? Если не работает, то уберите упоминания bottle итд из вопроса, для простоты и общности (чтобы большему кругу людей могло помочь). Эта проблема к Питону малое отношение имеет. Убедитесь ещё раз, что никакие антивирусы, файерволы (в том числе встроенные в систему) не активированы. Обновите вопрос со всей информацией, накопленной в комментариях.

Comment: у меня была такая же ошибка и я уже научился на ней. попробуйте воспользоватся моим ответом ниже.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде указаны настройки `host='192.168.0.198', port=8080` и это не правильно. Дело в том, что эта настройка указывает на то, какой компьютер и по какому порту имеет доступ к данному серверу/директории. Для того, чтобы у вас все заработало и вы имели доступ к серверу/директории с любого компьютера, вам необходимо выставить вот такие настройки `host='0.0.0.0', port=8080`. Теперь вы сможете входить на веб страницу, расположенную на сервере через `ip-сервера:8080/`. Если же, вы хотите чтобы сервер использовал порт `80`, просто замените `8080` на `80`. Но! При использовании порта `80`, запускать нужно будет данный сервер через `sudo`.

Есть аналогичные фреймворки подобные `Bottle`, к примеру `Flask`. Все они используют одну и туже настройку. Советую вам внимательно читать документацию.

Comment: это неверно: *"какой компьютер и по какому порту имеет доступ к данному серверу/директории"*. `host='192.168.0.198'` не является ip *клиента*, который к серверу пытается обратиться. `host='192.168.0.198'` указывает по какому адресу *сервер* слушать будет (`'0.0.0.0'` означает слушать на *всех* сетевых интерфейсах).

Comment: У меня ведь это работает.

Comment: объяснение может быть ошибочным и одновременно обходной вариант может работать (это ведёт к  [cargo-cult programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)). При отсутствии понимания, решение может перестать работать/вести к нежелательным побочным эффектам как это произошло с [лекарством от цинги, которое помогло Британскую империю построить.](http://mentalfloss.com/article.php?id=24149)